# Handling mouse events in Typescript with JQuery, while keeping strong typing

Tags: jquery, typescript, types

I am currently working on a project that uses JQuery within Typescript code.  One thing I am trying to do is pass a mouse event attached to a JQuery element to a wrapper class.  See example code below:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

export class Test {
  ele: JQuery;
  constructor() {
    this.ele = $('<div>Hello World</div>');
    this.ele.mousedown((evt) => { this.my_mousedown(evt); });
  }

  my_mousedown(evt: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(evt);
  }
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that the evt being passed is of the wrong type:

```
Argument of type Event<HTMLElement | null> is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent'
```

So, I then tried to change my_mousedown to:  `my_mousedown(Event<HTMLElement | null>` and get an error of:

```
Event is not generic.
```

Finally, I converted evt to its original event in the JQuery call (to a raw Event type), but then evt does not have any of the mouse specific calls (e.g.- `clientX`) available.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there are separate Event interface loaded from JQuery.  The way I got things working was to assign the event type to JQuery.Event.  i.e.:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

export class Test {
  ele: JQuery;

  constructor() {
    this.ele = $('<div>Hello World</div>');
    this.ele.mousedown((evt) => { this.my_mousedown(evt); });
  }

  my_mousedown(evt: JQuery.Event) {
    console.log(evt);
  }
}
```